# Distributing classes or namespaces

Tags: c#, programming-languages

I would have a question related rather to process of team programming than programming itselft. If you are a programmer working in a team and you are responsible for particular part of the software - you deliver namespace or classes? I mean, in reality, I think that programmer creates more than one class so creating a namespace to provide the other programmers with seems to me to be correct. Is that correct? I am trying to get some knowledge before I try to apply to same junior programming position..Thank you guys

Comment: Namespaces logically group classes. So if they fit in the same namespace put them in one. But don't use a namespace named after a person. The responsibility for a piece of code can change with time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your senior developer defines a task for you and you going to do it, may be is reading, improving some functions, creating some function, or creating a class, if you do your startup projects well he give you more opportunity may be you work on specific application (bigger than a namespace), it depends on your working power and knowledge.

Comment: Alg: Well, but what if someone uses the same class name as I do? That is why I want to use namespaces.

Comment: When you learned, If you want to work with C#, each time you want to define a class it will be defined it on a specific namespace, you can change the name of namespace, don't worry about this things, there are too many tools to avoid confilict and you will create too many namespaces, when you want to create a specific class may be you talk with your major about its design, the thing which is not important is the same class name.